# Different width CSS columns

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm using CSS Columns, eg:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content {
    column-count: 2;
}
```

However I want to have my columns different widths when using `column-width`.

Is that possible at all? I guess there is no way to use percentages either?

Comment: The link provided in the above comment says it all (no, you can't have different sizes for CSS3 columns) but I would like to suggest you use a `<table></table>`

Comment: Or `display: table` instead.

Comment: I can't use tables as the content is dynamic and it needs to span multiple columns - ie; I'm not able to break the content up. But alas, I had to come up with another way to separate the content so I could return it as two pieces instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is NO CORRECT way to set different column widths with CSS columns.

**Why it won't work**

`column-width` property only species the optimal width. The final output will be stretched or shrinked based on the available parent width. So it is not the right property to use when you need fixed or different column widths.
Ex:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  column-width: 40px;
}
```

There is room for two 40px wide columns inside the 100px wide element. In order to fill the available space the actual column width will be increased to 50px.

```
div {
  width: 40px;
  column-width: 45px;
}
```

The available space is smaller than the specified column width and the actual column width will therefore be decreased.

**Tweak**

In case you have 2 columns, you can set a -ve `margin-right` to get different column widths. This works with more than 2 columns but is limited to just 2 widths.

**Feasible Solution**

You can use `tables` or `display:table` instead to achieve similar results.

Comment: What's the point of having a `column-width` declaration?